# How can i select multiple rows on behalf of same id in second table?

Tags: mysql, node.js, join

I have a table named "profile"  like this

```
profile_id     name     state      location

    1          Alex     Houston    Park Lane
```

I have second table named "tags" like this

```
tag_id     profile_id     tag_title
  1           1            finance
  2           1           accounting
  3           1            audit
```

I have third table named "trust_admin_aum" like this

```
tier_d     profile _id    min_price     max_price    fee
  1           1              400         500          5
  2           1              750         1200        12
  3           2              900         1500         15
```

There could be multiple tiers for same profile.

My scenario is this that user enters a tag, state and min_price to search and i have to search on following conditions

- tag should be match first if user entered tag's profile is in db or not
- then match the state whether user entered state is matching to any profile with that tag
- if above both conditions true then check that is there any profile that has <= min_aum_price that user enter min_price in trust_admin_aum table table

like this

```
result : {
 profile_id : 1,
 name : alex,
 state : Houston,
 location : Park Lane,
 tag_title : finance,
 tags : finance,accounting
}
```

I have tried this query

```
SELECT p.*, IFNULL(GROUP_CONCAT(t1.tag_title), '') AS tags FROM basicprofile AS p JOIN profile_tags AS t1 ON p.profile_id = t1.profile_id JOIN profile_tags AS t2 ON t1.profile_id = t2.profile_id INNER JOIN trust_admin_aum AS taum ON taum.profile_id = p.profile_id WHERE p.state LIKE '%Houston%' AND t2.tag_title LIKE '%finance%' AND taum.min_price <=800 GROUP BY p.profile_id
```

But this query is returning tags twice like this

```
result : {
 profile_id : 1,
 name : alex,
 state : Houston,
 location : Park Lane,
 tag_title : finance,
 tags : finance,accounting,auditing,finance,accounting,auditing
}
```

How can i get rid of this twice tags?

Comment: You can't have multiple `tag_title:` properties in an object, property names have to be distinct.

Comment: so just tell me how can i retrieve profile with all tags that matches user input tag?

Comment: It should be an array: `tag_title: ["finance", "accounting", "audit"]`

Comment: so how can i retrieve like this?

Comment: It's in my answer.

Comment: Why do you say the names of the tables are `profile` and `tags`, but then use `basicprofile` and `profile_tags` in the query?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GROUP_CONCAT` to get all the tags in a comma-separated array, then you can split this into an array in the object.

```
SELECT p.*, IFNULL(GROUP_CONCAT(t1.tag_title), '') AS tags
FROM basicprofile AS p
JOIN profile_tags AS t1 ON p.profile_id = t1.profile_id
JOIN profile_tags AS t2 ON t1.profile_id = t2.profile_id
WHERE t2.tag_title LIKE '%finance%'
GROUP BY p.profile_id
```

When you're creating the object, you do this to create the array of tags:

```
obj.tag_title = row.tags == "" : [] ? row.tags.split(",");
```

Comment: i mentioned the query what i tried by myself but i am not getting result that i need. that;s why i posted here. if you don't want to help so ok no problem

Comment: Post your query in the question.

Comment: Use `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t1.tag_title)` to get rid of duplicate tags.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, select all matching tags with users, then join the users to tags again 
in order to get a list of all users with the specified tag and all of the tags for those users.

In the query below, alias *a* id s list of matching tags. Alias *b* is a list of matching users. 
Lastly, alias *c* is a list of all tags for users *b*.

```
SELECT 
    b.*, 
    c.*
FROM `profile_tags` a
JOIN `basicprofile` b
    ON a.`profile_id` = b.`profile_id` 
JOIN `profile_tags` c
ON c.`profile_id` = b.`profile_id`
WHERE a.`tag_title` like '%finance%'
GROUP BY b.`profile_id`,c.`tag_title`
ORDER BY b.`profile_id`,c.`tag_title`;
```

Comment: Did you want one row per profile, with one column showing all tags?

Comment: @SloanThrasher Look at the desired object he posted in the question.

Comment: @Barmar: Aah! It's that whole reading thing... LOL Should have seen that.